# ¿how to correct a closing message that repeat twice in a Windows Forms VS C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

¿how to correct a closing message that repeat twice Windows Forms VS C#?

Have to solve this situation in a development of a desktop application whit Visual Studio and C#.
A confirmation closing message is repeating twice when the user desire exit the application.
I made a Form base and inherit the closing advice(for the  X button top right corner and the logout button option 2) to the others. Forms are linked on to another but when I try to close the others forms and select Yes to close, the advice ask me again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J97X6.jpg)

Here are the codes I put.
For Inherit from Form Base:

```
   public partial class SelectUsuario : FormBase
```

Code of the Form Base for the close confirmation:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    {
        Application.Exit(); 
    }
}

public void FormBase_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro(a) que desea salir del sistema?",
          "Consulta",
          MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
          MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; //Cancela el cerrado del formulario
    }
```

And the code to link forms:

```
    private void pbxUsuarioOps_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        IG_UsuOPs irUsuarioOPs = new IG_UsuOPs();
        irUsuarioOPs.Show();
     }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you focus on the actual problem instead of pasting directly the whole school problem including "Hello everyone Have to solve this situation in visual studio and C#" ;-)

Comment: Don't put the FormClosing event handler in the base form, only the derived form class.

Comment: I am not sure by mean how to correct a closing message that repeat twice. Do you want to two closing message or one closing message? Or you can provide a completed code example with me so that I can fully understand your meaning.

Comment: I want only one closing message. But two options to exit the program. The problem is the message is repeating 2 times in the others forms.

Comment: I have tested the code you provided, I can not reproduce your problem. The message is only repeating 1 times for me. You can check if other code affect the app.

Comment: Thanks for your help, not problem when launch the forms apart one by one. The problem is when run full application and navigates form to form and try to exit from the button option 2. I made a short video to give a example of the error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJynBaL9T8o.